# Angular factory and module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am currently learning how to do MEAN Stack programming and I have encountered some code I cannot understand. I have tried to search on Google but still did not understand it.

Below is the code:

```
angular.module('todoService', [])

.factory('Todos', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/todos');
        },
        create : function(todoData) {
            return $http.post('/api/todos', todoData);
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Could anyone explain what .factory() is actually doing? Also, what are the parameter 'Todos' and todoService for? The code is from this [source](https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular).

Comment: services/factories/providers (_same thing_) are located on a separate layer from controllers and can share some logic across the app for convenience (so that you don't have to repeat your code). You can inject your factory into a controller: `function($scope,Todos){...}` and use its functions with `var promise = Todos.get();`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I can finally understand how and why the factories/ services work together with controllers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [AngularJS Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) is a provider in your AngularJS Module that returns a set of functions.

This factory will be injectable in your AngularJS Controllers, where you can use your factory's methods in your controllers by injecting the dependency.

```
angular.module('todoService').controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'Todos', function($scope, Todos) {
    $scope.somethingToStore = Todos.get();
}]);
```

*As Aleksey said*, `$http` service returns a promise, so it will be better to do:

```
Todos.get().then(function(response){
    $scope.somethingToStore = response.data;
}
```

To explain elements of your piece of code:

- `Todos` is your factory name
- `todoService` is your angular module name

Comment: (_note that_ `$http` _returns a promise_) Better: `Todos.get().then((res)=>{$scope.somethingToStore=res.data;})`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey you are right! It was for the example of factory usage.

Comment: @Zooly, Thank you for the explanation! I still have one more question I would like to ask. Where does the 'todoData' and 'id' come from?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks! I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @ApplePie you pass them as parameters: `Todos.create(your_data)`, `Todos.delete(your_id)`

Comment: They're params of your factory function. Imagine using : `Todos.create(data)` or `Todos.delete(14)` . This is the aim of using factories/services: you can reuse parametrable functions in different cases

Comment: @Zooly, Thank you for making this so much clearer for me. Now, I have a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: I'm glad it could help you! Don't hesitate to validate this answer to "close" this question